# DNS pre-resolve at server

Tags: php, dns, ip, prefetch

Is there a way to resolve `DNS` at server (using `PHP`), then include that pre-resolved IP address with domain name in `html`? So client's browser fetches directly from that IP without having a need to resolve `DNS` first?

Here is a bit more clarification. My `PHP` generated page has many external links to `js`, `css` and image files from different domains. It takes much time when `DNS` is resolved on clients' browsers. It can be done very fast on server but I don't want to links those resources directly from IP address. Instead I want something that tells browser that the domain example.com is hosted at `1.1.1.1` for example and no need to perform a `DNS lookup`.

Is it possible? or can there be a workaround?

Some thing like `dns-prefetch` with a value or attribute?

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://example.com" value="1.1.1.1" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way, is it ok to link resources from an IP address directly? like this 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://1.1.1.1/media/system/js/mootools.js"></script>

some people say that it is considered a malware (of course that is false) by some antivirus suites?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can resolve dns-name to IP.

1. While PHP can't do this, you can create a test file on your server. After that you fetch request for his file. According OSI model, DNS client will resolve DNS name->IP, after that you will have IP in your HTTP headers, because your real query depend on IP of server.
2. Low level. Windows and Linux both have an API for resolving DNS name -> IP. So you can use their functions in C++ to get IP without test file.
3. Or you can construct DNS message: DNS-message => UDP-datagram => IP-package. After you send it to DNS-server and wait for answer.

Your DNS-server IP you can find in your config.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your answer. I don't need or access C++, now windows or DNS server is a question here. I know domain name and it's IP at server in php. When sending HTML, my resources are linked from domain name. Usually client's browser or OS resolve that domain name. I want to avoid this step. Instead I want client browser to use the pre-resolved IP that I want to send in html. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, I thought you need to get IP address of server.

Comment: @IAdam If your have one, then you can use it in url instead of dns-name. For example: <image src="http://1.1.1.1/images/1.jpg" />. It's valid because all requests has IP in address, not dns-name.

Comment: @IAdam. For info. Browser or OS resolve nothing. DNS->IP resolving happens during session between your dns-client and dns-server, mainly at dns-server side. It's basics of net architecture. Browser and OS only caching DNS->IP map.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, some some malware checkers consider a resource linked to an IP address as a malware. Plus that is also a minus point for SEO.